# Why was Heaviside perplexed by this property of the gravitational potential?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, history

When reading an article (by Heaviside, linked below), I came across this sentence:

> For it must be confessed that the exhaustion of potential energy from
> a universal medium is a very unintelligible and mysterious matter.
> When matter is infinitely widely separated, and the forces are least,
> the potential energy is at its greatest, and when the potential energy
> is most exhausted, the forces are most energetic!

But I thought that the force only depends on the derivative of the potential at that position and not its actual value i.e. $F = - \frac{dU}{dx} $. So why is Heaviside making this point?

I guess the first sentence is referencing the ether, but I still dont understand why Heaviside is confused. What physical intuition led him to the idea that the relationship between gravitational force and potential energy is somehow 'backwards'?

Here is the article: https://sergf.ru/Heavisid.htm

Comment: It's quite possible that he just didn't appreciate that potential energy isn't "stuff" to be used up rather than a numerical property of a configuration of particles that is unique only up to a uniform offset. Those kind of subtleties can escape anyone really, and especially those around as these ideas are still being developed. (Sure, 200 years after Newton, but then again, the caloric theory was still likely around at the time, and they still thought there was an ether, and so from that perspective, maybe the idea makes sense!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article about this subject on the website 'mathpages'. The article is titled [Why Maxwell couldn't explain gravity](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath613/kmath613.htm)

Heaviside's thinking was strongly influenced by Maxwell's work.

Incidentally, to understand Maxwell's perspective on electromagnetism it is very helpful to read the treatment [On physical lines of force](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/On_Physical_Linesa_of_Force) (1861) (available on wikisource) that preceded Maxwell's large work 'A Dynamical Theory of the Electromagnetic Field (1865)'

(Note: while Maxwell uses a mechanical model he is not committed to the implementation details. Rather: pushing for a detailed model allows him to set up mathematical expressions for various relations; relations that will be valid for *any* model of how electromagnetism works. That is, the mathematics of Maxwell's model transcends the implementation details.)